# Radiogroup keyboard navigation

Tags: extjs, extjs6, keyboard-navigation

I have a radio group that is set in a table layout:

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2ehg

If you navigate around that radio group with left, right, up and down keys, the behaviour is unintuitive. I have searched the code and tried to debug the `focus` event on the radios, but did not find how/where ExtJS code navigates through the components.

How can I improve the keyboard navigation such that it behaves natural?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `keyMap` config and listening on the navigation key events you can prevent the browser default, calculate the new position and set it.
See the working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2el0).

It reacts more than you would expect. When you are on the first item and you press the up-button the new focused item is the last one in the row.

You may have to tweak left and right accordingly to fit your needs.

```
// get the id for the component from the event
const getPureId = (event) => event.target.id.split('-').splice(0, 2).join('-');
const columnCount = 2;
const maxIndex = 5;
const minIndex = 0;

// config of the panel ...
keyMap : {
    [Ext.event.Event.DOWN]: (event, panel) => {
        var pureId = getPureId(event);
        var comp = Ext.get(pureId).component;
        var pos = panel.items.indexOf(comp);
        var newPos = pos + columnCount;

        // when the newPos is outside of our boundaries we calculate the new one
        // based on the columnCount
        if (newPos > maxIndex) {
            newPos = newPos % (columnCount + 1);
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        panel
          .getComponent(newPos)
          .focus()
          .setValue(true);
    }, [Ext.event.Event.UP]: (event, panel) => {
        var pureId = getPureId(event);
        var comp = Ext.get(pureId).component;
        var pos = panel.items.indexOf(comp);
        var newPos = pos - columnCount;

        // when the newPos is outside of our boundaries we calculate the new one
        // based on the maxIndex
        if (newPos < minIndex) {
            newPos = newPos + maxIndex + 1;
        }

        event.preventDefault();
        panel
          .getComponent(newPos)
          .focus()
          .setValue(true);
    }
},
// more config of the panel ...
```